# Saving unserializable class

Tags: .net, serialization

I write the programm which work with Windows Registry i want to save some Microsoft::Win32::RegistryKey in binary mode.  I want to use Serialization but that class not serialazale.  do i need to create my own serialazable class  or there is some more easy way to save this class in binary mode in .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one option here: **Create your own "wrapper" for your needs** (it can be serializable class as well).

Answer (score 0):

You should either create your own serializable class to do that, or you could create a method for saving the relevant data from the non-serializable class.

Answer (score 0):

how do you plan to serialize it? it is just a wrapper over winapi structure. you can't set any property of it, they are read-only.